# Scala Interpreter: anyway to get the line of a compile error?

Tags: scala, error-handling, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I am using the scala interpreter to run some user defined script. for this I use the "IMain" class. Works like a charm except when it comes to report the line where a compile error happen.
To get the error line number, I just parse the interpreter output message, it is in the form < console>:***lineNumber***: error: ...

The problem is that the line number seems to change depending on the nature of the error and the enclosing scope (within a def or not).

This happens also with the REPL, for example:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_24).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a=7
a: Int = 7

scala> a.toString2
<console>:9: error: value toString2 is not a member of Int
              a.toString2
                ^

scala> a2.toString
<console>:8: error: not found: value a2
              a2.toString
              ^

scala> a.toString.length3
<console>:9: error: value length3 is not a member of java.lang.String
              a.toString.length3
                         ^
```

I would expect all error messages to start with "< console>:1" since the error is in the first line of the code to interpret...

Using the IMain class, is there another way to get the error line number ? (in addition to incorrect results, parsing the output feels kind of a hack...)

Comment: The numbers you get stand for the position of the error in the line and not the position of the line itself.

Comment: Are you using the IMain compile() method, or the IMain interpret() method?

Comment: So far I was using IMain interpret, that worked fine with Scala 2.9.0.1

Comment: I just switch to Scala 2.9.1.final before writing this question. The first time I tried, the behavior was same as with 2.9.0.1 (as you can see in the original question). Now, for some reason, I get the same line number: 8 in both cases (but 1 in case of "g}")

Answer (score 1):

Part of the answer is that what you type isn't what the scala interpreter is really running.

You can see this with `scala -Xprint:parser` : (I'm using scala 2.8.1, so that accounts for some of the difference)

```
scala> a.toString2
[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {
  object line2$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      import line0$object.$iw.$iw.a;
      object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        val res0 = a.toString2
      }
    }
  }
}

<console>:7: error: value toString2 is not a member of Int
       a.toString2
         ^
```

versus:

```
scala> a2.toString
[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {
  object line3$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        val res1 = a2.toString
      }
    }
  }
}

<console>:6: error: not found: value a2
       a2.toString
       ^
```

Compare the output after both lines. See the extra line in the first bit of output that says:

```
 import line0$object.$iw.$iw.a;
```

? That extra import line accounts for the difference you're seeing in line numbers.

So now what you need is some way for the IMain class to tell you how much stuff it's added to the top of the code before the error. (That still won't completely fix things - see the error line you get for `g}`)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this option will surely be helpful to understand what's going on